# escape characters not working with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string containing HTML escape characters (for `<`and `>`) that I am trying to render inside a `div` using innerHTML. the escaped characters are not supposed to be rendered like normal html, but rather as text. However, they still do, so is there a work around for this?

**NOTE:** the objective is to display a **few** (meaning not all) tags as normal text.

Here is an example implementation:

```
var string = "<div>yolo</div>";

string = string.replace(/</g, '&lt;'); //replaces all '<' with its escape character
string = string.replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); //replaces all '>' with its escape character

string = string.replace(/(=|%|\/|\*|-|,|;|\+|<|>)/g, "<span class=\"sc\">$1</span>");

//the last line adds special formatting 
//to certain characters using CSS (not shown)
//and a span tag with class, "sc".
//this is the reason that I cannot just simply
//use innertext instead of innerhtml

document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

**P.S.** please give an answer in pure JavaScript. I do not care if you add a jQuery solution, I just need a pure javascript one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qqsefuqe/1/ - what is the expected output

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qqsefuqe/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/qqsefuqe/3/

Comment: it works fine if you don't replace the `;` with a span: http://jsfiddle.net/k7jp16k9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work properly because you're replacing the `;`s with `<spans>`. Try replacing the whole `&lt;` *first* to prevent your span-replacer from breaking the entities.

e.g.

```js
var string = "<div>yolo</div>";

string = string.replace(/</g, '&lt;'); //replaces all '<' with its escape character
string = string.replace(/>/g, '&gt;'); //replaces all '>' with its escape character

string = string.replace(/(&lt;|&gt;|=|%|\/|\*|-|,|;|\+|<|>)/g, "<span class=\"sc\">$1</span>");

//the last line adds special formatting 
//to certain characters using CSS (not shown)
//and a span tag with class, "sc".
//this is the reason that I cannot just simply
//use innertext instead of innerhtml

document.body.innerHTML = string;
```

```css
.sc {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery, you may want to deal with `text()` instead of `innerHTML()`.

Comment: OP *specifically stated* for a **non-jQuery solution**

Comment: I understood 'I do not care if you add a jQuery solution' as we could add a jQuery solution.

Comment: See the comment block in the code, it explains why this doesn't work for the OP's use case.